# Mule - can't install devkit

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I followed the [instruction](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+an+Anypoint+Connector+Project) but it keeps giving me error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Anypoint Devkit Extension 1.0.2.201410031957 (org.mule.tooling.incubator.devkit.extension.feature.group 1.0.2.201410031957)
  Missing requirement: org.mule.tooling.devkit 1.0.2.201410031957 (org.mule.tooling.devkit 1.0.2.201410031957) requires 'bundle org.mule.tooling.utils [4.1.0,4.2.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Anypoint Devkit Extension 1.0.2.201410031957 (org.mule.tooling.incubator.devkit.extension.feature.group 1.0.2.201410031957)
    To: org.mule.tooling.devkit [1.0.2.201410031957]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed `Anypoint Devkit Extension  1.0.2.201410031957  org.mule.tooling.incubator.devkit.extension.feature.group` (the one present of the addons plugin software site) succesfully on my `Anypoint Studio October 2014 Release Version: 4.1.1 Build Id: 201411041003`.

Please, upgrade to the lastest Studio and use the aforementioned sofware site.

Comment: oops, I thought the Studio would update itself so I just assume I had the latest one. Thanks.